# Query parameters with postman and Spring

Tags: java, spring, postman

Can someone explain to me why given this controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/gamification")
public class GamificationController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GamificationController.class);

    @Autowired
    private GameServiceImpl gameService;


    @GetMapping("/retrieve-stats/?user={userId}")
    ResponseEntity<GameStats> getUserStats(@RequestParam("userId") String userId){
        logger.debug("UserId is {}", userId);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(gameService.retrieveStatsForUser(Long.parseLong(userId)));
    }

}
```

and this pm request

[image]

I get a 404 NOT FOUND?

and If I add brackets to the query parameter, I get a 400 BAD REQUEST

[image]

Comment: The `RequestParam` name is `userId` not `user`. You should try with `userId` in place of `user`. URL should be `http://localhost:8080/gamification/retrieve-stats?userId=123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the  `/?user={userId}` from `@GetMapping` as well as from the 1st Postman screenshot request and Construct it like the below one.

```
@GetMapping("/retrieve-stats")
ResponseEntity<GameStats> getUserStats(@RequestParam("userId") String userId){
    logger.debug("UserId is {}", userId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(gameService.retrieveStatsForUser(Long.parseLong(userId)));
}
```

PS: And you don't have to cast it `Long.parseLong`, you can declare the parameter with the type `@RequestParam("userId") Long userId`, Spring is smart enough to autobox the variable type based on its type declartion.